# Mean value theorem inequality problem.

Tags: calculus, inequality

So I'm having trouble trying to solve this problem:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers such that $a \geqslant b \geqslant 1$. Using the Mean value Theorem prove that
>   $$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\leqslant a-b$$

I honestly don't even know how to start, so I was wondering if someone could please lend me a hand? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\ln x$ and apply Mean Value Theorem to $f(x)$ on the inerval $[b,a]$. Then there is $c\in(b,a)$ such that $f(a)-f(b)=f'(c)(a-b)$.
But, $f'(c)=\frac{1}{c}$ and $1\le b< c< a$, so $\frac{1}{c}<1$.
Resumming, 
$$\ln(a/b)=\ln a-\ln b=\frac{1}{c}(a-b)< a-b.$$
This arguments works if $a<b$. Otherwise, $\ln a-\ln b=0=a-b$ and you have equality.

Answer (score 7):

If $a=b$, we are done. Otherwise, by the MVT, there is some $c\in(b,a)$ such that
$$
\frac{\log(a)-\log(b)}{a-b}=\frac{1}{c}\leq 1
$$
where the last inequality is because $c\geq b\geq 1$.

Comment: Why c can be equal to b?

Comment: @guillemfigols Oh you can write $c>b$ if you’d like. I just need $c\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$I:= \displaystyle{\int_{b}^{a}} \dfrac{1}{x}dx= \log a- \log b$;

MVT of integration:

$I= \dfrac{1}{r} \displaystyle{\int_{b}^{a}} 1 dx =(1/r)(a-b)$, where $r \in [b,a]$.

Finally

$\log a -\log b=(1/r)(a-b) \le a-b$, since $r\ge1$.